# Where does the phrase pattern “X! Whiskey! Sexy!” originate?

Tags: etymology, phrases

From around 2006-2007, the blog “Crazy Apple Rumors” sometimes used the phrase “Technology! Whiskey! Sexy!” in its posts (see e.g. http://crazyapplerumors.com/2007/01/09/post-keynote-keynote-live-blog/).

I’d assumed this was a neologism, but then I saw [this article](http://www.mudvillegazette.com/000561.html) from 2004 using the phrase “Democracy, Whiskey, Sexy”.

What’s the derivation of these two?

Comment: Probably from here: http://www.petrifiedtruth.com/archives/000201.html

Comment: @Philoto: ah! Excellent. Pop that in as an answer, and we can close this question off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what America was going to bring to Iraq after the war in early 2000's [according to one Iraqi citizen](http://petrifiedtruth.com/archives/000201.html):

> NAJAF, Iraq, April 2 - In the giddy spirit of the day, nothing could quite top the wish list bellowed out by one man in the throng of people greeting American troops from the 101st Airborne Division who marched into town today. What, the man was asked, did he hope to see now that the Baath Party had been driven from power in his town? What would the Americans bring?
>
> "Democracy," the man said, his voice rising to lift each word to greater prominence. "Whiskey. And sexy!" Around him, the crowd roared its approval.